# Technically correct way to handle Ctrl-AnyKey events in ProcessCmdKey of RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have created a derived RichTextBox class as follows:

```
public partial class FACTConsole : RichTextBox {
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if ((keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.A)) ||
            (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Z)) ||
            (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V))) {
            return true;
        }
        //:
        //: Other keys and combinations
        //:
    }
}
```

This works as expected for those specific Ctrl-key combinations.

But my intention is to disable any Ctrl-key combination (Ctrl+AnyKey).

I tried changing my code as follows:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if (keyData == Keys.Control) {
        return true;
    }
    //:
    //: Other keys and combinations
    //:
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work as expected. In fact, it results in very strange behavior which is even difficult to step-through in debug mode. What is the technically correct way to handle this requirement?

By the way: I do not want to use the KeyDown event for this case, because my ProcessCmdKey handles many other cases and keys, which misbehave if I also have a KeyDown with `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`

Comment: @RandRandom, Any specific reason you edited out the VS .Net version from my title? I thought it was relevant information to obtain answers specific to the framework.

Comment: Tags in title: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks.